# How to skip footer/trailer record while loading csv file to hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

The file is CSV with comma delimited.

Framework for ingesting CSV file is present. 
Header from the same file is skipped by:

```
Df.Option(“header”, “true”)
```

But trailer record in the same spark package, I am unable to skip it same logic.

Please help with this data ingestion.

Comment: You can try setting this property in hive table, TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1', 'skip.footer.line.count'='1'); # when 1 line to skipped as header or footer. Any concerns this way?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this reply:

[spark how to remove last line in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763806/spark-how-to-remove-last-line-in-a-csv-file)

A copy from the same reply:

```
val total = df.count();
val withoutFooter = df.zipWithIndex()
                        .filter(x => x._2 < total - 3)
                        .map (x => x._1)
```